# what is the meaning of a "free" and a "natural"

Tags: terminology

**natural** transform,
**natural** condition,
**free** object,
**free** functor , etc.

what are the general meaning of a word "**free**" and "**natural**" in mathematics ?
when does it be attached?

edited: I don't want to know meaning of above example. I want to know why it was chose to attach

Comment: Did you look already at wikipedia, for example? [Free object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object). And [free functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+functor) in nLab.

Comment: thanks for reply. I want to know a general meaning of "free" and "natural" in mathmatics not meaning of above example.

Comment: Essentially everything in math can be interpreted as an object or a functor, so those cover pretty much all the uses of "free" you could encounter